# Turn off default encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have

```
<%= Html.TextArea("PostContent.Description", Model.PostContent.Description)%>
```

if I enter

```
"I am <script>alert()</script> After scrip",


I will get<p>I am &lt;script&gt;alert()&lt;/script&gt; After scrip</p>
```

by default.

but i don't want this behavior. how can i turn off this default behavior only for this text box

Note that i just want to handle this text box only.

[mvc 2]

Answer (score 3):

In order to prevent the binder from escaping the HTML characters you can mark the `Description` property with an `[AllowHtml]` attribute:

```
public class ModelPostContent
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't check the MVC version. Too bad I started with MVC 3 and didn't learn the subtleties

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<textarea name="<%= HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName("PostContent.Description") %>"> 
    <%= Model.PostContent.Description %>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found that it is not possible to avoid default encoding by mvc